# Disable crawlers inside robots.txt file for all funnel pages

Tags: reactjs, web, web-crawler, robots.txt

If inside the `robots.txt` of my app has this line:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /banana
```

Question:
Do all other following URLs down the funnel for example:

```
/banana-signup and
/banana-payment
```

also have crawlers disabled on them or no?

The second question is:
if `/banana` has crawlers disabled, does that mean when user search in Google for example type in `companyname/banana`, it will not show up in search results?

What exactly does "disable crawlers on a URL" do?

Comment: Remember `robots.txt` is just polite advice and robots can and will be rude. Have you used the [webmaster tools](https://search.google.com/search-console/about)?

Comment: does `companyname` here represent your domain name?  like `https://example.com/banana`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes. 
what if users search in google "companyname /banana"
or type in search bar ( not url )
https://example.com/banana